# Gradle Replace token

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle filtering to replace a token in one log4j.xml using below code.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
task copylog4jEnvSpecific(type:Copy){
       from("$config_dir/"+"$env")
       into("$webAppDir/WEB-INF/classes")
       include "**/log4j.xml"
       filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [LOG_HOME: project.rootDir])
}
```

but I am getting an error saying

```
Execution failed for task ':copylog4jEnvSpecific'.
```

> Could not copy file 'C:\Users\<>\rws\conf\<>\configuration\dev\log4j.xml' to 'C:\Users\<>\rws\build\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.xml'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need more information here. Run your build with `--stacktrace` maybe we can get some more info there.

I presume `C:\Users\<>\rws` is your project path?

When do you run the task? maybe the `build` directory does not exist yet?
As well what is creating `WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\` ?

You can make sure that your task is executed after the build task with:

```
copylog4jEnvSpecific.dependsOn build
```

Comment: It seems project.rootDir return java.io.File and filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [LOG_HOME: project.rootDir]) expecting a string. Fixed with below code

 filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [LOG_HOME: FilenameUtils.separatorsToSystem(project.rootDir.getAbsolutePath()+"\\logs")])

Anyway Thanks for the help.

Comment: @shashi voting is for thanking ;) no problem have a great day.